# Batch - delete and paste specific lines in txt file

Tags: batch-file, html-lists

I want to create a batch while which delete specific lines in and paste there text.

Example:

//file.txt//

```
COM=1
BaudRate=4800
DataBits=7
Parity=e
StopBits=1
```

I want to let the batch file delete line2 and paste to line2 new text (varies according to the assignment) to let it look like this:

```
COM=1
BaudRate=300
DataBits=7
Parity=e
StopBits=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
@echo off
ren file.txt file.tmp

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (file.tmp) do (
  if "%%a" EQU "BaudRate" (
    Echo BaudRate=300>> file.txt
  ) else (
  echo %%a=%%b>> file.txt
  )
)

type file.txt
Echo. & Echo is file.txt correct. Enter if yes. Close window if no
del file.tmp
```

Which does what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks ... I try it:  file.txt rename to file.tmp and in commandline : in not now expected  :-(

Comment: @MartinPokorny Sorry about that, small typo. Rename file.tmp to file.txt and try my new code. It should work now

Comment: @Monocraft:  I would like to ask you for help. I have another problem with similar batch code. May I send it you by email ? My email: martin.pokorny89@yahoo.com

Comment: @MartinPokorny You can post it on stackoverflow with the tag batch-file and either myself or another experienced user can help you. If you'd prefer email: monacrafter@gmail.com and I will reply to you in about a day